# Unable to debug Azure Functions Core Tools in VSCode

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am currently having trouble to debug my Azure Functions Core Tools in VS Code.
I am using the npm package `azure-functions-core-tools@2`.
As i read on many resources `func host start` / `func start` should always start the node process in with `--inspect=9229`. As you can see this is not the case in my setup:

```
[4/30/19 4:51:25 AM] Starting language worker process:node  "/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools/bin/workers/node/dist/src/nodejsWorker.js" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 50426 --workerId 3e909143-72a3-4779-99c7-376ab3aba92b --requestId 656a9413-e705-4db8-b09f-da44fb1f991d --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
[4/30/19 4:51:25 AM] node process with Id=92 started
[4/30/19 4:51:25 AM] Generating 1 job function(s)
[...]
[4/30/19 4:51:25 AM] Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
```

Also all attempts of changing the hosting environment failed. I tried to add `FUNCTIONS_CORETOOLS_ENVIRONMENT` to my local configuration, resulting in an error:

```
An item with the same key has already been added. Key: FUNCTIONS_CORETOOLS_ENVIRONMENT
```

I tried to add several environment variables in my launch and task settings, using `--debug`, changing project settings. Nothing works.

I am currently running this on the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and except this it works really well.

Anyone has a clue on what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think debug is enabled by default. You will have to set the language worker arguments for this to work as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#local-debugging).

1. **In `local.settings.json`**

   > To debug locally, add `"languageWorkers:node:arguments": "--inspect=5858"` under `Values` in your local.settings.json file and attach a debugger to port 5858.
2. **With `func` CLI**
   You could set this by using the [`--language-worker` argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#start)

```
func host start --language-worker -- --inspect=5858
```

3. **In VS Code**
   If you are developing using VS Code and the Azure Functions extension, the `--inspect` is added automatically as the corresponding environment variable is set in `.vscode/tasks.json`

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "runFunctionsHost",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "func host start",
      "isBackground": true,
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always"
      },
      "problemMatcher": "$func-watch",
      "options": {
        "env": {
          "languageWorkers__node__arguments": "--inspect=5858"
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": "installExtensions"
    },
    {
      "label": "installExtensions",
      "command": "func extensions install",
      "type": "shell",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You could also set this environment variable directly if you'd like instead of adding it in `local.settings.json` too.